# Adding an extension in Sphinx (Python Documentation Generator) configuration file

Tags: python, macos, python-sphinx

I want to use Sphinx as a documentation generator. When I try to run the **make html** command, I have the following error :

`Extension error:
Could not import extension sphinxcontrib.httpdomain (exception: No module named sphinxcontrib.httpdomain)
make: *** [html] Error 1`

I've found this web page explaining that I have to manually add the extension to the Sphinx configuration file https://pythonhosted.org/sphinxcontrib-httpdomain/#module-sphinxcontrib.httpdomain

But I can't find this configuration file.

Do you have any idea where I could find it ? I'm on Mac OS X

Answer (score 0):

The configuration is in the `source` folder of your Sphinx project. It is named `conf.py` and contains an `extensions` option which should look like this:

```
# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
    'sphinx.ext.todo',
    ...
]
```